# Need regex with two decimals for angular directive

Tags: regex, angular

I try to use this directive but I cannot set up regex for two decimals

How to set up regex, to example that allows numbers like 
34.21 | 32.4 | 32 | 67. | 77.

Comment: Maybe [`^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Is4I52/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Test cases:

```
1234   *matches*
12.23   *matches*
4343.2   *matches*
12123.   *matches*
.12   *does not match*
1.234   *does not match*
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But your regex does not work. Check please example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpeqpc-wrfxyq?file=app/input-overview-example.ts

Comment: I think the problem that regex must allows numbers with dot at the ends, like 45.  56.  78.

Comment: 12123.   *does not match*   -    must be matched

Comment: @VasiliyMazhekin you did not mention that earlier in the question. I've edited now.